# Compressing multiple static layers to single layer to make web map loading faster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, performance, compression

In our web application there are many layers to be loaded, this cause the loading of map very slow.

I am seeking a way to compress multiple static layers to a single layer to make the loading faster.

All the layers from an enterprise geodatabase (version 10).

Is it possible to compress layers?

Comment: you can merge them if they are the same geometry type (point, line or polygon) but that makes a new layer. You can save them as a group layer which will keep the symbology by grouping them in ArcMap and then select on the group layer and *save as layer file*, then you can drag-n-drop the group layer into ArcMap later. Is this what you mean?

Comment: They should be there, grouped into a *new group layer*. Re-reading the question I think that this approach will not help as it's a web service. Read the answer by PolyGeo and have another look at your spatial indexing and database tuning.. what data source are you using for your web service? shapefile, SDE, file/personal geodatabase?

Comment: Hi Michael, I am using an enterprise geodatabase, and I found when I tried to save it as a layer file, I couldn't select a my enterprise database.

Comment: Layer files don't go inside a database, they are a file system object. Look instead at database tuning which can have a big impact on SDE data; if you are using standard spatial indexing then you might want to see if it's logical. Also, if possible make sure your data spatial reference matches your data frame spatial reference.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you review the Help page entitled [Managing the performance of ArcGIS map services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00sp00000012000000).

In particular I think you should look at the dot point from that page below:

> - Precompute information results when you can do so. For example, you can precompute the maps that are delivered with ArcGIS for Server and
>     use cached map services or basemap layers.

What you are describing sounds like a [Basemap layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000017000000).

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo. After I successfully create the new base layer and attempted to save as a layer file, I could not save it in my enterprise database, is it applicable to enterprise database?

Comment: From the documentation I was under the impression that it applied but I will defer to anyone with it installed who can advise/test.  A better option may be [cached map services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_cached_map_services/00sp0000001r000000/).